# Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>

Tags: angular

Here is the code I am having issues with.

```
this.filteredContacts = this.recipientsCtrl.valueChanges
  .startWith(null)
  .map(contact => contact ? this.filterContacts(contact) : 
this.contacts.slice());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import those operators from `rxjs/operators`:

```
import { startWith, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.filteredContacts = this.recipientsCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(null),
  map((contact) => contact ? this.filterContacts(contact) : this.contacts.slice())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`startWith`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/startWith) and [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) are operators. You could pipe them in

```js
this.filteredContacts = this.recipientsCtrl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(null),
    map(contact => contact ? this.filterContacts(contact) : this.contacts.slice())
  );
```

Comment: it stating that it can not fine name "startWith" and "Map"

Comment: @Joshua You need to import startWith and map